# How do I insert a 'PDF Macro' into an existing Confluence page using REST API

Tags: confluence-rest-api

I have been attempting to insert a 'PDF Macro' onto a Confluence page using the REST API and obviously am missing something.  I have successfully created the page using REST API as well as attach the PDF to the page but am struggling to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
curl -v -S -u user:password -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","body":{"storage":{"value":"<ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"viewpdf\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"name\"><ri:attachment ri:filename=\"RequirementCoverageReport.pdf\"/><\/ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:page=\"My Page\"<\/ac:parameter><\/ac:structured-macro>","representation":"storage", "container":{"type":"page","id":"78086157"}}}}' https://myurl/confluence/rest/api/content/78086157 | python -mjson.tool
```

And here is the exception that is being thrown;

```
{
"message": "Edit Content id mismatch", 
"statusCode": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I update my Confluence 5 pages with this :

```
 <ac:structured-macro ac:name="viewpdf"><ac:parameter ac:name="name"><ri:attachment ri:filename="name_of_the_attached_pdf" /></ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro>
```

It works very well. But im using jQuery/Javascript only.
If you need a jQuery solution, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error trying to update page content via REST API. I solved it by adding page ID to the root section of JSON:

```
{
    "id": 12345, <---- this was missing
    "version": {
        "number": 3
    },
    "type": "page",
    "title": "New title",
    "body": {
        "storage": {
            "value": "<p>New text.</p>",
            "representation": "storage"
        }
    }
}
```

Thus, in you case new version number is missed and page ID should be moved to the root section of the JSON.